# r retain non zero rows in case of duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, aggregate, data-transform

I have a dataset with duplicate rows if we group by two columns

```
 ID    Group       Value    
   1     z1       0 
   1     z1       0.81 
   2     z2       2.89 
   2     z2       1.53
   3     z1       -0.23
   3     z1       0
   4     z3       10.75
   4     z3       8.13
   5     x2       0.45
   5     x2       1.43
```

```
df <- tibble(
  ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5),
  Group = c("z1", "z1", "z2", "z2", "z1", "z1", "z3", "z3", "x2", "x2"),
  Value = c(0, 0.81, 2.89, 1.53, -0.23, 0, 10.75, 8.13, 0.45, 1.43)
)
```

I am trying to retain only non-zero rows if there are duplicate rows when grouping by `ID` and `Group` columns

Expected output

```
 ID    Group       Value    
 
   1     z1       0.81 

   2     z2       2.89 
   2     z2       1.53

   3     z1       -0.23

   4     z3       10.75
   4     z3       8.13

   5     x2       0.45
   5     x2       1.43
```

The rows with 0s in ID 1 and 3 are excluded. This is what I tried so far

```
df %>%
group_by(ID, GroupID) %>%
filter(if (any(duplicated(.) Value != 0 else TRUE) %>%
ungroup()
```

I have 22000 rows in my original dataset, the code above took a long time and did not converge.
I then tried this.

```
df %>%
group_by(ID, GroupID) %>%
slice(if (any(duplicated(.))) which(Value != 0) else 1:n()) %>%
ungroup()
```

This is still not solving the problem, not giving me the expected results, the code takes a long time , and nothing seems to happen.

Any suggestion on how to tweak this code is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If there was a unique ID and Group but it had a 0, you would want to keep it? In other words, there are no duplicates, but it's value is 0.

Comment: @AdrianFletcher, Hi Adrian yes, that is correct. If there is an unique ID+Group and it is 0 then keep it,  if there are multiple rows for ID+Group and one any are 0 or 0s then exclude them and keep only non-zeros for the combination of ID+Group

Comment: I suspect your sample data does not mimic the real data sufficiently, please edit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(Value != 0)
```

```
 ID Group Value
1  1    z1  0.81
2  2    z2  2.89
3  2    z2  1.53
4  3    z1 -0.23
5  4    z3 10.75
6  4    z3  8.13
7  5    x2  0.45
8  5    x2  1.43
```

Comment: good point, the goal is to remove 0s only if duplicate when groupby ID+Group